# rendering in nodejs using express to html

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get values from nodejs into HTML. I've seen lot of answers, but none of them is working.

here what I've done so far:

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>

</head>
<body>

    <div> 
          <a id="test" name="test"> <%=name%></a>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
   const express =require('express')
const app = express();
var os = require( 'os' );
var path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT ||2000;


app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'))
})


app.get('/test', (req, res)=> {

    var name = 454;

    res.render( "/index.html", {name:name});

  });

app.listen(2001)
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. but  it doesn't work as expected. 
any idea how may I solve this ? 
thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a folder *views* and put your *index.ejs* right there (though, I am not sure, the extension have to be *.ejs*).

Then set the engine with:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

And change your routing to:

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.render('index', { name: 'Test' });
});
```

**Edit:** I have used the [express application generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) and also checked [Using template engines with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

**Edit:** According to the extension *.ejs*:

> One thing to note is that all files in which ejs syntax are used in
>   must be saved with a .ejs extension [...]

Taken from [Using EJS as a Template Engine in your Express App](https://medium.com/@Linda_Ikechukwu/https-medium-com-linda-ikechukwu-using-ejs-as-a-template-engine-in-your-express-app-cb3d82c15e17), not from the official docs.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It did work, but my problem is that I need to integrat it in already made html, is there a way to render just a specific element in the html page? thanks in again !